# Why is the closing bracket a special character that must be escaped to be taken as a literal?

Tags: regex

It is clear that an opening bracket "(", among other characters, must be escaped (prefixed by a backslash) for the regex to contain a "literal opening bracket": Because there are regex options for which "(" is a lead-in.

But how comes the same holds true for the closing bracket ")"? There is no syntax construct that has ")" as a lead-in token, is there?

**So why do I have to escape closing brackets for them to be taken literally?**

Of course, the same question could be asked for the other closing brackets as well.

Sorry for this being a "why is this so?" question. It might possibly be un-answerable. But if there *is* a good reason, the only way to get to know it is by asking!

Addendum:
The rationale behind this question is: 
For example, http://www.regexguru.com/2008/12/dont-escape-literal-characters-that-arent-metacharacters/ gives good reasons not to prefix characters that don´t need prefixing.

And imho, the closing bracket does not need prefixing in most cases:
Since a closing bracket without an opening one is not part of a regex group, I find it totally unlogical that it needs to be escaped in this case anyways.

Comment: Lots of downvotes, but noone commenting the reason for the downvote -- "cool".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume you want to match a group holding a closing bracket. Without escaping, this would look like this `())`. Escaping the bracket like `(\))` makes it much easier (if not even possible) for the regular expression to be parsed correctly and unambiguously.

In the (unescaped) regular expression `(\w))`, does the closing bracket belong to the group, or not, i.e., is the group closed by the first or the second `)`? E.g., for the string `abc)d`, does it match `c` or `c)`?

Of course one *could* omit some of the escape characters in case the meaning is not ambiguous (and the regex parser allows to do so) but what would it help? You save a character here and there, but each time you encounter a `)` or another special character you have to think: "Is this a control character or a character to be matched? Is it ambiguous?" Better make it clear and consistent.

Answer (score 2):

As a more specific example for tobias_k's answer:

Look at the following regex:

```
(a*))
```

looking at the string `bbaaa)bb` will it capture `aaa`or `aaa)`?

The result is clear with

```
(a*\))
```

versus

```
(a*)\)
```

Comment: Sorry, I already added a very similar example just seconds before you posted your answer... +1

Comment: In my world, (a*)) should result in an error since the second non-literal closing bracket does not match any opening bracket.

Answer (score 1):

**Of course, the same question could be asked for the other closing brackets as well.**

No that's not correct (or may vary with one regex engine to another).

In Javascript regex engine `]` and `}` don't need to be escaped.

See this example:

```
var x = 'brackets)}]';

x.match(/]/); // works

x.match(/}/); // works

x.match(/)/); // failes
```

Only for the case 3, it fails with the error **`Unmatched ')'`**

Comment: Hm. The mandatory prefixing of the closing bracket in JavaScript has nothing to do with regexes, does it?

Comment: It is very much regex thing since what you are suplying in match method is actually a regex.

Comment: Yes but the closing bracket before the ";" in case 3 is closing the match argument list, and is not part of the regex, right? it was NOT prefixed because it is a regex special character but a JavaScript closing bracket.

Comment: What is inside `/` and `/` is actually regex and that's where complaining about. `)` before `;` is actually closing bracket for `match` method.

Comment: Ah, I see -- I was not familiar (or had forgotten about) the meaning of the forward slash pair...thanks!